# What is the trick in pAddress & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1) to get the page's base address

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Following function is used to get the page's base address of an address which is inside this page:

```
void* GetPageAddress(void* pAddress)
{
    return (void*)((ULONG_PTR)pAddress & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1));
}
```

But I couldn't quite get it, what is the trick it plays here?

Conclusion:
Personally, I think Amardeep's explanation plus Alex B's example are best answers. As Alex B's answer has already been voted up, I would like to accept Amardeep's answer as the official one to highlight it! Thanks you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What it does is clears the bits of the address that fit within the mask created by the page size.  Effectively it gets the first valid address of a block.

PAGE_SIZE must be a power of 2 and is represented by a single bit set in the address.

The mask is created by subtracting one from PAGE_SIZE.  That effectively sets all the bits that are a lower order than the page size bit.  The ~ then complements all those bits to zero and sets all the bits that are a higher order than the mask.  The & then effectively strips all the lower bits away, leaving the actual base address of the page containing the original address.

Comment: "The ~ then complements all those bits to zero and sets all the bits that are a higher order than the mask" ---- To match the size of left handle operand of &, right?

Comment: The ~ will return the same size as its operand.  In this case, if PAGE_SIZE is just a macro defined to a literal number, it will default to whatever 'int' is on your target platform, probably 32 bits.  The code example you gave will not work on a 64 bit system.  It would need:  return (void*)((ULONG_PTR)pAddress & ~(void *)(PAGE_SIZE - 1));

Answer (score 14):

The function clears low bits of a given address, which yields the address of its page.

For example, if `PAGE_SIZE` is 4096, then in 32-bit binary:

```
   PAGE_SIZE      = 00000000000000000001000000000000b
   PAGE_SIZE - 1  = 00000000000000000000111111111111b
 ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1) = 11111111111111111111000000000000b
```

If you bitwise-and it with a 32-bit address, it will turn lower bits into zeros, *rounding the address to the nearest 4096-byte page address.*

```
 ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1)             = 11111111111111111111000000000000b
                    pAddress  = 11010010100101110110110100100100b
 ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1) & pAddress  = 11010010100101110110000000000000b
```

So, in decimal, original address is `3533139236`, page address (address with lower bits stripped) is `3533135872 = 862582 x 4096`, is a multiple of `4096`.

Answer (score 4):

When PAGE_SIZE is some power of 2 (say 4096 for example), this clears all the bits below those that specify the page.

Comment: Yea, seems the PAGE_SIZE has to be power of 2, or else the result is wrong, but then why ~(PAGE_SIZE-1), I think we could just use PAGE_SIZE

Comment: @Dbger: PAGE_SIZE, if a power of two is represented by a single bit.  You need all the bits set that are lower order than that one in order to create a mask of the correct size.

Comment: If PAGE_SIZE is a power of 2, then complementing it will give you a mask with only a single zero bit, which doesn't help much.

Comment: Mentioning sign extension when the 32-bit value gets expanded to 64-bits might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a tricky way of clearing the low order bits.

Another way to implement it might be

```
void* GetPageAddress(void* pAddress)
{
    return pAddress - pAddress%PAGE_SIZE;
}
```

That probably won't compile, as you need to cast the types a bit, bit it shows the algorithm.

Effectively it is getting the largest multiple of PAGE_SIZE that is less than pAddress.